# Calling an array

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to find out how to call two parts of an array in one go. Is this possible?

Example

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); 
echo $cars[0,1];
```

Or do I need to call the array for each piece of information separately as below?

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); 
echo $cars[0] . $cars[1];
```

Comment: You've unlocked the code. ;)

Comment: You have to call each one separately unless you want something that is multi-line, which seems to defeat your purpose.

Comment: Your question is unclear, thus impossible to answer how it currently stands. It is unclear what you actually mean by "to call two parts of an array". You cannot "call" an array or elements of an array, an array is not a method of function. You can _access_ elements of an array, for example to get their value. If that is what you mean then please edit your existing question for clarification. Otherwise try to explain what it actually is, so what your desired outcome is so that we are able to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_slice

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); 
echo implode(', ', array_slice($cars, 0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) which returns an array consisting of the extracted elements and specify 0 as the offset.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
echo implode(', ', array_splice($cars, 0, 2));
```

Output

> Volvo, BMW